# Removing characters from elements of array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, iterator

Given:

```
array = ["1289", "12 apples", "12546", "123"]
```

How can I print out all the elements of the array, with "12" removed? The answer I am looking for should apply even if the array had hundreds of elements.

Comment: Iterate and gsub?

Comment: What is the expected result in the following cases: "aples12", "ap12les"? In other words, "12" must be taken away in any position or just in the begining of the string?

Comment: Just the beginning for this one. Although I would love to know how to do this with 12 in any position.

Comment: `#gsub` with a global regular expression would easily do this, @Emma-Claire.

Comment: @Emma-Claire I provided an answer that properly removes 12 from any position along with extraneous whitespace. If you want the whitespace, just remove the \s+ portion.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map` with `gsub` (or `sub`, when `12` appears only once in the string):

```
array = [ "1289", "12 apples", "12546", "123"]
array.map { |word| word.gsub('12', '') }
#=> ["89", " apples", "5463", "3"]
```

Comment: I wonder why my post was down-voted several times, but no one explained why. The OP made clear in the comments that she wants to *do this with 12 in any position* (not just the beginning) and my answer does that...

Comment: The same happened to me. Not sure who is doing drive-by downvoting on this question. I voted to close as Unclear What You're Asking, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following.

```
array = [ "1289", "12 apples", "1254612", "123"]
```

**Solution 1**  (Using [string#tr](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-tr) method)

```
array.each{|string| puts string.tr("/12(\s+)?/", '')}

## Output
"89"
"apples"
"546"
"3"
```

**Solution 2** (Using [string#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) method)

```
array.each{|string| puts string.gsub(/12(\s+)?/, '')}

## Output
"89"
"apples"
"546"
"3"
```